# Alternatives to Facebook in browser?

Tags: facebook

I get frustrated with FB in a browser window.

Is there an app that under the hood uses the FB API that can do any/most of the following.

- Show me all my notifications in chronolgical order.
- Allow me to have multiple news feeds, and shove my high school friends in one, my politics groups in one, etc.
- Allows me to configure when something gets reshown to me.  E.g. just because I've commented on something doesn't mean I want to see it again everytime someone comments.  I *do* want to see if someone replied to me.
- Allows me to right click on a post and say "ignore any buy and sell post with the phrase "baby clothes" in it.
- Ignore all sponsored posts.
- not show me my memories.
- filter all birthday notifications.